# Facebook App Platform Development

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I´m starting to develop Facebook Applications. I already have readen the FPP, but, it is not enough clear for me what exactly I can, and what I can´t do in my applications. Things like use Google Ads, post into user wall, etc. Please help me saying what you have sucessfully used in your applications, without having troubles with application removals.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only allows to show ads from Facebook's list of approved 3rd party ad providers (Google Adwords is not one of them).

A lot of the rules in FPP are directly aimed at spamming or leaking users' personal information, however a lot of applications walk a tight rope there and Facebook does not always enforce them.

The two big things that I have seen applications getting shutdown or notices for are:

1) Allowing user to post inappropriate content without a way to quickly and effectively remove them.  We had a poll program circa 2009 that reached high volume and users have posted some very controversial images.  We got a slap on the wrist for getting a high number of complains from user not being able to handle them quickly enough.

2) Passing personally identifiable FB information to 3rd party.  This was a problem with ad networks specifically, where applications are sending user's FB ID directly to ad networks who uses that information to profile their users.  Instead, you should send the "3rd party id" that is provided by facebook and accessible via a Graph API call for all users.

Comment: Does the second point apply to use of Google Analytics or another external tracking service?

Comment: Use of Google Analytics is OK.  It doesn't pass the user's FB Id over to Google, so it plays fine with FB's rules.